# MongoDB projection into array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The below document has the dob of student and its parent's dob.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a31573a3b1f89cb895abd3"), 
    "dob" : {
        "isodate" : ISODate("1996-01-21T18:30:00.000+0000")
    }, 
    "parent" : [
        {
            "dob" : {
                "isodate" : ISODate("1956-07-21T18:30:00.000+0000")
            }, 
            "type" : "father"
        }, 
        {
            "dob" : {
                "isodate" : ISODate("1958-11-01T18:30:00.000+0000")
            }, 
            "type" : "mother"
        }
    ]
}
```

In one of the application use case, it is better to receive output in the below format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a31573a3b1f89cb895abd3"), 
    "dob" : {
        "isodate" : ISODate("1996-01-21T18:30:00.000+0000")
    },
    "type" : "student"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a31573a3b1f89cb895abd3"), 
    "dob" : {
        "isodate" : ISODate("1956-07-21T18:30:00.000+0000")
    }, 
    "type" : "father"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56a31573a3b1f89cb895abd3"), 
    "dob" : {
        "isodate" : ISODate("1958-11-01T18:30:00.000+0000")
    }, 
    "type" : "mother"
}
```

The approach is to `$project` the fields into array and then `$unwind` that array. However, projection doesn't allow me to create array.

I believe `$group` and its associated aggregation cannot be used as my operations are on the same document in the pipeline.

Is this possible?
Note - i have the flexibility to change the document design as well.

Comment: @blakes-seven any thoughts

Comment: can u explain more detail?

Comment: i have added solution for 3.2, anything similar for 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

**For Mongo 3.0**

Here I have included a `[null]` array which gives me the option to insert array in projection using a combination of $setDiffernce and $cond. The output of this is given to $setUnion with `$parent` array.

```
db.p1.aggregate(
{ "$project": {
        "allVal": { 
          '$setUnion': [
            {"$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": [null],
                    "as": "type",
                    "in": { "$cond": [
                        {"$eq": ["$$type", null]},
                        {dob:"$dob", type:{$literal:'student'}},
                        null                        
                    ]}
                }},
                [null] 
            ]}

            , 
            '$parent'
           ]
        }
    }},
    {$unwind : '$allVal'}

)
```

**For mongo 3.2**

Feels heaven as I have avoided $setDifference and $literal hack adjustments.

```
db.p1.aggregate([
{
    $project:{
        parent : 1,
        type: {$literal : 'student'},
        'dob.isodate' : 1
    }
},
{
    $project:{
        allValues: { $setUnion: [ [{dob:"$dob", type:'$type'}], "$parent" ] }
    }
},
{
    $unwind : '$allValues'
}
])
```

In the first projection, I am adding a new field called type

In the 2nd projection, I am creating a new array with 2 different nodes of the same document.

Currently this solution works for Mongo 3.2

Comment: Why do you think the second option only work in version 3.2? `$literal` was added in 2.6 here is the [release note](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#release-notes-for-mongodb-2-6). Also there is much better way to do this in version 3.0 onward and 3.2

Comment: $project as array was added in 3.2

Comment: "Project New Array Fields" is available from 3.2  https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project . let me know if this is possible in 3.0 or earlier :). thanks